# Delete specific columns (based on percentage missing value) coming from a list in a dataset using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe "df" and a list "float64list" of numerical data columns.
I would like to delete of columns that are in the "float64list" from df if the percentage of missing value is above 60%

I have this working for the whole df but I don't know how to filter the columns from the list before

```
df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[0]*0.6,how='all',axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, could you please show what df and the list look like, and the expected output?

Comment: https://ibb.co/Pr0sNFk
Here is a snapshot of my DF and the list:
https://ibb.co/bR1rhpz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy `dataframe` and `float64list`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [pd.NA, pd.NA, 3, pd.NA, 9],
        "col2": [0, 4, pd.NA, 7, 1],
        "col3": ["a", "b", pd.NA, "d", "e"],
        "col4": [pd.NA, "b", pd.NA, "d", pd.NA],
    }
)

float64list = ["col1", "col2"]
```

Here is one way to do it by [concatenating](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (1) df without columns in `float64list` and (2) df without columns with NA values above threshold :

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(float64list)],
        df[float64list].dropna(thresh=df.shape[0] * 0.6, how="all", axis=1),
    ],
    axis=1,
).pipe(lambda df_: df_.reindex(columns=sorted(df_.columns)))
```

```py
   col2  col3  col4
0     0     a  <NA>
1     4     b     b
2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3     7     d     d
4     1     e  <NA>
```